# Replace a digit in a sentence using re.sub() in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use `re.sub()` to replace the total score in the sentence.
For example, in `Your score for quiz01 is 6/8.`, I want to replace the total score to `9`, the expected output is `Your score for quiz01 is 6/9.`.

I tried the code below but it keeps return `(?!([a-zA-Z]+))(?:.+?)([0-9]\/9). **`. How should I modify the regex to replace the digit correctly?

```
import re
s = '** Your score for quiz01 is 6/8. **'

print(re.sub(r'(?!([a-zA-Z]+))(?:.+?)([0-9]\/[0-9])', r'(?!([a-zA-Z]+))(?:.+?)([0-9]\/9)', s))

# result print as (?!([a-zA-Z]+))(?:.+?)([0-9]\/9). **
```

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(.*\d/)\d+', r'\g<1>9', s)`

Comment: If the `.**` part should be there, perhaps `\b(\d+/)\d+(?=\. \*\*)` https://regex101.com/r/0VTy1P/1

Comment: Please  provide more details: is the number always the last in the string? What if there are more occurrences?

Comment: We can't help you if you keep silent, we need to know details.

Comment: the number will be always in the same format, and the total score wont be > 9

Comment: So, does `re.sub(r'(\d/)\d(?!\d)', r'\g<1>9', s)` work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your help! I tried it just now and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(\d/)\d(?!\d)', r'\g<1>9', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0oEu9/1). The regex matches

- `(\d/)` - Group 1 (referred to with the `\g<1>` unambiguous backreference from the replacement pattern; the `\g<N>` syntax is required since, after the backreference, there is a digit): a digit and a `/` char
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?!\d)` - not followed with any other digit.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/47WiEs):

```
import re
s = "Your score for quiz01 is 6/8."
print( re.sub(r"(\d/)\d(?!\d)", r"\g<1>9", s) )
# => Your score for quiz01 is 6/9.
```